# Import contributions without name

Tags: civicontribute, import, fields

Previously I could import contributions without name (contact ID was enough).

I no longer have this option. It now demands first and last names.

Is there a workaround? My raw data often has variations of the name and I want to keep my original.

Lal

Answer (score 2):

By default, CiviCRM requires at least one of email, first name, or last name. You can change this at Contacts > Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts, creating a new rule and setting it for usage when unsupervised, or, more appropriately, by selecting it as the Dedupe Rule when importing at Contacts > Import Contacts. Beware of setting the rule to identify duplicates too loosely, as you will end up with lots of duplicates in your database. This is a complicated, tricky area...good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the time, Joe. But you seem to be talking about importing contacts, while I'm importing contributions.

Nevertheless, I'll see if I can find an analog in the import contributions system.

Best wishes,
Lal